# Attempting to fix performance issues with Google App Engine - issues scaling up instance class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

Our Google App Engine app is running very slowly, and I'm attempting to solve the problem by following the steps found here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings

It says to configure the frontend instance class by editing the settings file.  I believe the file in question in our app is app.yaml, though I'm not positive.  I attempted to add some new settings to app.yaml:

```
application: app
version: 2-01
runtime: python27
### Lines I added ###
instance_class: B8
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 11
  idle_timeout: 10m
### END lines added ###
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
```

But when I try to deploy with these changes it gives this error:

Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Your application currently has custom performance settings that are not compatible with the Modules feature. You must either clear or migrate these application-level settings before you can upload a non-default module. See the Performance section of the Application Settings page of the Admin Console for more information.
--- end server output ---

I looked all throughout the admin console and can't find a performance section, or a page called Application Settings for that matter.  I suppose the admin console's structure has changed since this error message.  But it leaves me at a loss for how to fix the issue in order to increase the number of instances in the app.  How do I get rid of this error and increase the instances?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are attempting to configure here. You have set an instance class of B8 for front end instances which is not a valid configuration for front end instances.

Before blindly making changes you need to ask yourself some questions. Is your application "slow" because of poor design in terms of data loading / non parallel operations on the backend?

You can review such functionality within the cloud monitoring viewer & with appstats: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

However, if what in fact you are are after is configuring appengines "scaling" configuration settings what your after is probably more inline with the following:

```
application: app
version: 2-01
runtime: python27
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
 automatic_scaling:
   min_idle_instances: 1
   max_idle_instances: automatic
   min_pending_latency: automatic
   max_pending_latency: automatic
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about appstats, I'll try installing that and see what I find.  When I tried replacing the settings I had with what you posted above it gave me an error about the redundant "automatic_scaling."  So I removed that and it went back to giving me the error about custom performance settings.  All I want to do is scale up our instances so the app doesn't run as slowly.  As I didn't program the project to begin with, have just inherited it, diagnosing the performance issues in the app may be beyond me at the moment.  Is there any simple way to just scale up to improve performance?

Comment: If you had a redundant message, that more than likely means you have that same setting twice in your app.yaml file. If you can review the existing app.yaml file and update your question with the existing "scaling" settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using modules (is not the same than importing modules), you have to configure performace settins in each module.yaml file.  The app.yaml or the settings in the admin panel are no longer used when you start deploying modules.

Comment: I don't think the app uses modules, it doesn't have any module.yaml files at any rate.  If that's the case do I need to convert the app so it does use modules?  I looked for instructions on how to do that and couldn't find them.  Or is there a way to configure performance in an non-module app?